# How would I get a distinct list of Categories associated through two many to many relationships with Laravel 5/Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have kind of a complicated data model and I am trying to write my query with Laravel 5/Eloquent and not just plain ol' SQL. My SQL below works but I drank the kool-aid and I would like to get it working the 'right' way.

There is a [many to many relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many) between Actors and Poses and a [many to many polymorphic relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) between Poses and Categories.

What I would like to do is get a list of all distinct Categories associated to an Actor through its Poses.

#### SQL

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        categories.name,
        categories.parent_id
    FROM 
        actor_pose 
    JOIN 
        poses ON poses.id = actor_pose.pose_id
    JOIN 
        categorizables ON categorizables.categorizable_id = poses.id  
    JOIN
        categories ON categories.id = categorizables.category_id
    WHERE 
        actor_pose.actor_id = 1 AND
        categorizables.categorizable_type = "App\\Pose"
    ORDER BY
        parent_id
```

#### Database

**actors**
        id
        name

**poses**
        id
        name

**categories**
        id
        name
        parent_id

**categorizables**
        category_id
        categorizable_id
        categorizable_type

#### Code

**CategorizableTrait.php**

```
<?php namespace App;
trait CategorizableTrait {
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Category', 'categorizable');
    }
}
```

**Pose.php**

```
<?php namespace App;
class Pose extends Model
{
    use CategorizableTrait;
    public function actors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Actor')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Actor.php**

```
<?php namespace App;    
class Actor extends Model
{
    public function poses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pose')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Comment: Read this http://softonsofa.com/laravel-querying-any-level-far-relations-with-simple-trick/ And don't miss the comments from Joseph Silber - in L5.1 it will be possible with only collection methods.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer, your post worked great!

Answer (score 2):

The link to [SoftOnSofa](http://softonsofa.com/laravel-querying-any-level-far-relations-with-simple-trick/) from [Jarek Tkaczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784588/jarek-tkaczyk) had a clean solution that I ended up using.

I added this method to my Actor.php file.

**Actor.php**

```
public function getCategoriesAttribute()
{
    $categories = new Collection;
    $this->load(['poses.categories' => function ($q) use ( &$categories ) {
        $categories = $q->get()->unique();
    }]);
    return $categories->sortBy('order')->sortBy('parent_id');
}
```

The controller doesn't do anything special. In blade you access it as below.

**index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($actor->categories as $key => $category)
    {{ $category->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I think a lot of folks will find this extremely useful.  However, be careful with it.  I just implemented something similar on my own project for finding a user's permissions which I had to go through the roles table for.  For 10 users, it ran 28 queries.

Comment: Thanks. I did some tests and both this way and the way you suggested ran two queries. The raw query I originally had ran one, but it didn't return the eloquent collection.

Answer (score 1):

The `Collection` class has some very nice methods for handling this type of thing.  Just use `with()` to build your relationships and get the actor you want.  Loop through the relationships and add to the collection.

```
$categories = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
$actor = App\Actor::with('poses.categories')->find($actor_id);

foreach($actor->poses as $pose) {
    foreach($pose->categories as $catgegory) {
        $categories->add($catgegory);
    }
}

$categories = $categories->unique();
```

If you want all the actors on a page each with their unique categories, it's just everything nested inside of another loop.

```
$actors = App\Actor::with('poses.categories')->get();
$actor_categories = [];

foreach($actors as $actor) {
    $actor_categories[$actor->id] = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
    foreach($actor->poses as $pose) {
        foreach($pose->categories as $category) {
            $actor_categories[$actor->id]->add($category);
        }
    }
    $actor_categories[$actor->id] = $actor_categories[$actor->id]->unique();
}
```

You will end up with an array which you can pass to the view where the key is the actor's id and the value is a collection of unique categories.  For example, if you wanted to loop through actor 1's categories, you'd do something like...

```
foreach($actor_categories[1] as $category) {
    echo $category->name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ideally, I'd like it associated with the actor, so when I pulled up a list of actors, I could get the categories they belong to.

Comment: This would give you only categories associated with a certain actor.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unclear. I want to pull up many actors on one page. I still only want to see the categories as they relate to one actor.